# Can't get locale time on Date type

Tags: ios, swift

```
let date = datePicker.date
let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: date))
let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))
let minDate = currentDate
datePicker.minimumDate = minDate

realm.beginWrite()
let newItem = ToDoListItem()
newItem.date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))!
newItem.item = text
realm.add(newItem)
try! realm.commitWrite()
textView.text = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!) + "\n\(newItem.date)"
print("NewDate: \(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate!))")
```

I need current time but code is giving me Greenwich time. So I did this. In print I can get true result but in newItem.date is giving me wrong result. How can i fix this.

EDIT:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short
dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
let date = datePicker.date

let newDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: date))
let currentDate = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))

let minDate = currentDate
datePicker.minimumDate = minDate
realm.beginWrite()
let newItem = ToDoListItem()
newItem.date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))!
newItem.item = text
realm.add(newItem)
try! realm.commitWrite()
textView.text = dateFormatter.string(from: newDate!) + "\n\(newItem.date)"
print("NewDate: \(dateFormatter.string(from: currentDate!))")
```

Still not working.

Comment: There is nothing to fix. A date has no timezone. It is a point in time. When you print the date it will always display GMT unless you use DateFormatter to localize it and select a timezone

Comment: Btw show your date formatter declaration

Comment: I tried it. It is still not working @LeoDabus

Comment: Can you add output for both dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When writing dates in Realm, no date formatter is needed:

```swift
realm.beginWrite()
let newItem = ToDoListItem()
newItem.date = Date()  // not dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))!
newItem.item = text
realm.add(newItem)
try! realm.commitWrite()
```

Converting the `Date` to a `String` and back to a `Date` (with `dateFormatter.date(from: dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))!`) is inefficient and unnecessary.

When preparing the string for the text view, then use the formatter:

```swift
// use this

textView.text = dateFormatter.string(from: newItem.date)

// do not use string interpolation of `Date` objects, such as this
//
// textView.text = ... + "\n\(newItem.date)"
```

Where

```swift
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateStyle = .medium
dateFormatter.timeStyle = .short

// date formatter’s default to the current time zone, so this is not necessary
//
// dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current
```